# Display only items selected - Javascript replacing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to make a **"filter by"** selection, using dropdown button. 
Whenever the user clicks on a specific type of item (like clothes in my example), the html would show up only the items that match the criteria (only clothes). I could manage to select the items that I wanted and put in an array, however, when I try to replace the **div** with the new array the output is `[object HTML Element]`.
 Funny thing is if I `console.log` the array with a specific value, `(array[0])` it shows the html code that I need.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" >
                <a class="dropdown-item" onClick="filter('clothes')" >Clothes</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" onClick="filter('electronics')" >Electronics</a>
</div>

 <div id="testSearch">
            <section name="product"> 
                <img value="clothes" src="./some.jpg" alt="Clothes 01">
                <h5>Electronic</h5>
            </section>
                <section name="product"> 
                <img value="electronics" src="./some2.jpg" alt="Electronics 01">
                <h5>Electronic</h5>
            </section>

</div>

 <!-- My code has different sections with a variety of value/h5 -->

<script>
function filter(x) {

    var arraySearch = [];

    var input = document.getElementsByName('product');

    for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {

    if(input[i].innerHTML.indexOf(x) > 0 ) {
        arraySearch[i]= input[i];
        result = result + arraySearch[i];
        }

    }
    document.getElementById('testSearch').innerHTML = result;
    <!-- my html display only [object HTMLElement], if more than a section matches, then it displays the [object HTMLElement] times the number of sections matched -->

}

</script>
```

I expect the output of [object HTMLElement] to be the sections that match the criteria.

Comment: first off try defining `result` as a let. `let result = result + arraySearch[i];`

Comment: Hey there, I kind of forgot to put in my code here at Stack, but I declared the `var result = " " ;` before the loop. Even though I changed my code to what you recommend, it still has the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it! Pretty much what I needed was the `.outerHTML` when passing the array to the `var result.`

Here is the working code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" >
                <a class="dropdown-item" onClick="filter('clothes')" >Clothes</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" onClick="filter('electronics')" >Electronics</a>
</div>

 <div id="testSearch">
            <section name="product"> 
                <img value="clothes" src="./some.jpg" alt="Clothes 01">
                <h5>Electronic</h5>
            </section>
                <section name="product"> 
                <img value="electronics" src="./some2.jpg" alt="Electronics 01">
                <h5>Electronic</h5>
            </section>

</div>

 <!-- My code has different sections with a variety of value/h5 -->

<script>
function filter(x) {

    var arraySearch = [];

    var input = document.getElementsByName('product');
    var result = " ";

    for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {

    if(input[i].innerHTML.indexOf(x) > 0 ) {
        arraySearch[i]= input[i];
        result = result + arraySearch[i].outerHTML;
        }

    }
    document.getElementById('testSearch').innerHTML = result;

}

</script>
```

That is it. Hope it helps someone.